# wcscpy_s - buffer size when the pointer is not the start of the buffer?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I'm a little confused about the second parameter to [wcscpy_s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1esda9.aspx) and similar functions. Microsoft (on [wcscat_s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d45bbxx4.aspx)) points out that

> the second parameter is the total size of the buffer, not the
>   remaining size

Unfortunately, in the code sample following that remark, they point to the start of the destination buffer every time:

```
char buf[16];
strcpy_s(buf, 16, "Start");
strcat_s(buf, 16, " End");               // Correct
strcat_s(buf, 16 – strlen(buf), " End"); // Incorrect
```

So I'm left wondering... does their remark apply even when the pointer **isn't** to the start of a buffer? Or should I in fact be specifying the **remaining** bytes available in the buffer in such cases? Or does it somehow recognize the actual starting address of the buffer even if I pass something like `buf+1` as the first parameter?

Let's say I wanted to replace the basename in a path using `wcscpy_s`, is this proper?

```
#define BUFSIZE 11
wchar_t buf[BUFSIZE];
wchar_t *basename;
wcscpy_s(buf, BUFSIZE, L"C:\\foo.txt");
basename = PathFindFileNameW(buf);
wcscpy_s(basename, (BUFSIZE - ((size_t)basename - (size_t)buf)), L"bar.txt");
```

Comment: Should be the size as measured from the pointer you pass to the end of the buffer.  I think they meant that, for eg. `strcat_s`, you shouldn't subtract the length of the string it will append to even though it may end past the address you passed in.

Comment: The function cannot know anything about any supposed buffer space that might or might not exist before the pointer location passed. If you pass `ptr+1` to a function it cannot know anything about `ptr`.

Comment: The functions have no way of knowing where the original start of the buffer was if you passed a pointer into the middle of it... so it only makes sense to pass the length from the pointer you passed to the end.

Comment: @Dmitri yeah, pretty much what I thought. Just wish they'd be more clear about it. Unfortunately, maintaining the "relative" size is kind of a mess. I don't like my solution of casting pointers to `size_t`... Any ideas?

Comment: If you don't like maintaining the remaining size, use `wcscat_s` instead of `wcscpy_s`.

Comment: Just `BUFSIZE - (basename - buf)`... the casts are unnecessary because of the way pointer arithmetic works (`basename - buf` will give an appropriate integer type, representing the difference in `wchar_t`s).  You could also keep a pointer to just past the end of the buffer (eg. `wchar_t *bufend = buf + BUFSIZE;` and then use just `bufend - basename`.

Comment: The documentation is absolutely clear as-is.  The start of the buffer, *by definition*, is the pointer you passed.  If the buffer you're passing also happens to be part of a larger buffer, it's your job to keep track of that.